# Creating a "mergeable" toolbar with Prism regions?

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm developing a WPF application where I would like a common toolbar along the top of the screen (when I say "toolbar" it won't be a WPF ToolBar control, more likely just a series of image buttons resembling a Windows 8 app bar). I'm using Prism navigation.

What I had in mind was that this toolbar would live in the main window, and always be visible throughout the application. The toolbar would include a couple of standard buttons such as "Exit" and "Help".

Below the toolbar, the main window essentially just contains a large Prism region. When I navigate this region to a view (call it "view1") I want view1 to add additional buttons into the toolbar.

Now, "view1" may have Prism regions of its own, and when one of these is navigated to a view (call it "view2"), view2 should be able to add buttons of its own, alongside the "standard" main window buttons *and* the buttons added by view1.

It goes without saying that the relevant buttons should be removed when navigating away from a view.

I'm sure I could roll my own solution, but wondered if I could simplify things with Prism? I thought about putting a Prism region in the toolbar alongside the "standard" buttons. "view1" would then navigate this region to a view that basically just contains view1's buttons. This "view1 button view" could itself contain a region, that view2 could navigate to its own "button view". Is this viable, or is it going to get too complicated?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prism, but I achieved this in my own MVVM framework using an `ObservableCollection<DelegateCommand>` in the Main ViewModel and then adding / removing items from that based in the child ViewModels' life cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be complicating it a bit, or at least you lost me at the end...but that doesn't take much today!

A suggestion: Your "toolbar" could be, for example, some `ItemsControl` where your `ItemsSource` is a collection of some class `ToolBarOperation`. This class could contain a description to display to the user and an ICommand to perform when clicked. Style your `ItemsControl`'s items to be buttons and bind each button's command to your class's ICommand. This collection would be populated by the currently visible view's viewmodel (i.e. `View1`'s viewmodel would already know what commands it would be responsible to perform. When `View1` is loaded, fill the collection with `ViewModel1`'s list of `ToolBarOperation`.)

So, to answer your question, I don't think you need anything Prism specific (except maybe their implementation of `DelegateCommand`)...the "Controller pattern" discussed in the documentation might be helpful. But it shouldn't be hard to accomplish what you want with Prism alongside.

Comment: Yes it must be Friday. I wasn't thinking of the obvious (and simple) - to just use some kind of bindable collection. I'm still getting used to thinking in a WPF-oriented way, or "fourth dimensionally" as Doc Brown would say.